# Aligning two buttons to the center of a row

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have the following code snippet:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Gotham,
                 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;
                 background:#d95b23;width:170px;text-align:center;line-height:40px;
                 height:40px;display:block;font-size:15px;" href="%24%7BloginLink%7D">
                 Yes, Integrated</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Gotham, 
                 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;
                 background:#d95b23;width:170px;text-align:center;line-height:40px;
                 height:40px;display:block;font-size:15px;" href="%24%7BloginLink%7D">
                 No, Yet to Integrate</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Which is inside a row as two separate columns. Both buttons are in the extreme left and right. How do I arrange them close to each other and in the centre?

I have tried out adding margins and floats but it didn't work out.

Can someone give a quick help?

Comment: `<center>` tag?

Comment: <td align="center"> - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp

Comment: I see you obviously have issues with alignment. Even your code in your own question is not aligned.

Comment: @Andrew Will only alight the left button to the center. I want both the buttons close to each other and both of them together to be on the center

Comment: It will align both buttons to the center of the `<td>`, the problem is that your `<td>` are 2 different `width`. if they were the same width then the buttons would be in the center

Comment: @Andrew What would be possible solution?

Comment: You need to fix the  `colspan="2"` for some of your `<td>` as well as giving them a `center`. I will add in an answer, which fixes your HTML from the fiddle

Comment: Try codepen provided in my answer

Comment: @Azola The `<center>` element is obsolete. So is the `align` attribute: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just added float:left to the left button. I have also created a table with a green background so it's easier to spot

```html
<table style="width:100%;background:green;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Gotham,
               'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;
               background:#d95b23;width:170px;text-align:center;
               line-height:40px;height:40px;display:block;
               font-size:15px;float:right" href="%24%7BloginLink%7D">
         Yes, Integrated</a></td>
    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Gotham,
               'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;
               background:#d95b23;width:170px;text-align:center;
               line-height:40px;height:40px;display:block;
               font-size:15px;" href="%24%7BloginLink%7D">
         No, Yet to Integrate</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please check the fiddle and update this? I tried but didnt work out

Comment: Sure thing, take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/dymwd15n/ The problem was that the left td was much larger than the right one, so I've added width:50% to it, and then added float:right to the a tag inside. You can add some margins so they are not that close together, let me know if you need more help

Comment: @L L The buttons came to what I have expected, but the width of the texts above have halved :(

Comment: Just add `colspan="2"` to the above td, see updated snippet and let me know if it works please :) https://jsfiddle.net/dymwd15n/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Add this style for row which has your columns with buttons
tr {
display: flex;
justify content: center;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWGdKz)

Comment: It looks like this is for an e-mail, no chance of Flex helping there

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update to your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq6rwwqv/2/)

You need to add a `colspan` to the once that span over the 2 columns that contain your buttons, else the buttons wont know what size they should be and will also ignore sizing as the first `<td>` wants to be the size of the `<td>` above it.

```
<td colspan="2" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#666666;line-height:22px;">
                                    Help us assist you better. Let us know if you’ve successfully completed your payment gateway integration.
                                  </td>
```

Then once you have done that you need to add in your

```
<td align="center">
```

If you want to add in a little padding round your buttons you can add it onto the td like this:

```
<td align="center" style="padding:10px;">
```

The updated [fiddle with padding](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq6rwwqv/3/)

Comment: Thanks. This answer too helped me :)

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to nest the buttons inside another table, then centre that table within the row. The td with the fixed width can be used to adjust spacing between the buttons.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"> 
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Gotham,
                             'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;
                             background:#d95b23;width:170px;text-align:center;line-height:40px;
                             height:40px;display:block;font-size:15px;" href="%24%7BloginLink%7D">
                             Yes, Integrated</a>
                </td>
                <td width="10"></td>
                <td>
                    <a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:Gotham, 
                             'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;
                             background:#d95b23;width:170px;text-align:center;line-height:40px;
                             height:40px;display:block;font-size:15px;" href="%24%7BloginLink%7D">
                             No, Yet to Integrate</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Ajeesh I would say this is the best method above as float doesbt do to well at times. A three column table with Lett and right with CTA and middle acting as gutter is the best.